# How to make the props binding reactive when using 'createElement' function

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-reactivity

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false
Vue.config.productionTip = false
let modal = Vue.extend({
  template: `
<div class="modal">
  <p>Balance: {{ balance }}</p>
  <input @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)" :value="value">
  <button @click="$emit('input', balance)">ALL</button>
</div>
`,
  props: ['balance', 'value']
})

function makeComponent(data) {
  return { render(h) { return h(modal, data) } }
}

Vue.component('app', {
  template: `
<div>
  <p>Balance: {{ balance }}</p>
  <p>To withdraw:  {{ withdrawAmount }}</p>
  <p>Will remain: {{ balance - withdrawAmount }}</p>
  <button @click="onClick">Withdraw</button>
  <modal-container ref="container"/>
</div>`,
  data () {
    return {
      withdrawAmount: 0,
      balance: 123
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onClick () {
      this.$refs.container.show(makeComponent({
        props: {
          balance: String(this.balance),
          value: String(this.withdrawAmount)
        },
        on: {
          input: (value) => {
            this.withdrawAmount = Number(value)
          }
        }
      }))
    }
  }
})

Vue.component('modal-container', {
  template: `
<div>
   <component v-if="canShow" :is="modal"/>
</div>
`,
  data () {
    return { modal: undefined, canShow: false }
  },
  methods: {
    show (modal) {
      this.modal = modal
      this.canShow = true
    },
    hide () {
      this.canShow = false
      this.modal = undefined
    }
  }
})


new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

```css
.modal {
  background-color: gray; 
  width: 300px; 
  height: 100px; 
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

* {
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #2c3e50;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17-beta.0/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <app></app>
</div>
```

This is a simplified version of our application using [vue-js-modal](https://github.com/euvl/vue-js-modal). The basic Idea is that we pass a component declaration along with required [VNodeData](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#The-Data-Object-In-Depth) to the plugin function and it would append that component to a pre-defined DOM point with proper data bindings.

And our usecase is that:

1. User clicks 'Withdraw'
2. Modal pops up with an input field and static field displaying user's balance
3. User enters the amount he/she wants to withdraw and that amount and resulting balance are displayed in the callee component.

*There is a 'ALL' button besides the input field for user to easily enter a number equal to his/her balance*

**Problem**: When user clicks 'ALL', the 'modal' component fires an 'input' event with value of the balance and the callee component receives that event and updates its 'withdrawAmount'. But the 'withdrawAmount' is supposed to be passed back to the 'modal' as 'value' prop and further updates the input field, which doesn't happen.